# What mysql-java-connector should I use for MySQL4 database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, myisam

http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/ - What mysql-java-connector version should I use for accessing my MySQL4.1.22 database configured with MyISAM storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for Connector/J 5.1, it is new and compatible, as told in [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html)

Do you have some specific reason to use MyISAM? For example lack of transactions and no concept of foreign key will likely cause problems.

Comment: The latest MySQL 5.1.17 connector doesn't seem to work against the 4.1.22 database and hence looking for a connector which was certified to be used against 4.1.22

Comment: (corrected) How it doesn't work and what do you mean with certified? Oracle themselves claims that it should work, for example in release announcement: lists.mysql.com/announce/742